# Program that sorts lines in a text file by number of occurences

Tags: windows, text-editor, text-processing, text-search

I have a large text file with a lot of lines of terms. Some lines repeat themselves. I want a program that gives me the lines that appear most often in the entire document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux the command can read: `sort <filename> | uniq -c`

Missed the Windows part at first. On Windows the same can be accomplished when e.g. Cygwin has been installed or the sort and uniq from the GNU collection are installed.

Comment: The question is NOT tagged with Linux, it is with "Windows" instead ...

Comment: I can do that on Linux as well through a VM, thanks.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens there are also the [Gnu32 CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) which include `sort` and `uniq` (hm, a little dated – but there might be a newer fork available somewhere), there's Bash in Windows 10, there's [gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow), [busybox-w32](https://frippery.org/busybox/) and there's Cygwin and [CygwinPortable](https://github.com/CybeSystems/CygwinPortable). Oh, and there's [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) of course :)